# Set string in class with a set-function.

Tags: c++, string, function, class

I cant figure out why I can't change string className with the function player.setClassName(); . Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
//Functions.cpp

void classChoice(playerClass player) 
{
    int select = 0;
    string text = "Text";
    do {
        cin >> select;
        getchar();
        switch (select) {
        case 1:     
            player.setClassName(text);
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3: 
            break;
        default:
        }
    } while (select > 1 && select > 3);
}
```

the function im using to change className.

```
//PlayerClass.cpp

void playerClass::setClassName(string &className) {
    this->className = className;
}
```

playerclass

```
//PlayerClass.h

class playerClass : public playerCharacter, public Skills 
{
private:
   string className;
public:
   playerClass();
   playerClass(string className);
   virtual ~playerClass();

string getClassName();
void setClassName(string &className);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`classChoice()` accepts the `player` object **by value**, so it is operating on a *copy* of the object.  Any changes made to that copy will not be reflected in the original object that is passed to `classChoice()`.  If you want to update the original, you need to pass it **by reference** (or pointer) instead:

```
void classChoice(playerClass &player)
```

Also, `setClassName()` should accept its `string` input by `const` reference instead.  And `getClassName()` should be declared as `const`:

```
class playerClass : public ...
{
...
public:
   ...
   string getClassName() const;
   void setClassName(const string &className);
};

string playerClass::getClassName() const {
    return this->className;
}

void playerClass::setClassName(const string &className) {
    this->className = className;
}
```